# Create a ruby script installer for Linux OS

Tags: ruby, linux, installation

I wrote an application using ruby and I want to create an installer for that. I'm using Linux as OS.

I know there's the ruby script setup.rb written by Minero Aoki, but It's a bit harsh to understand by reading the source code and I'd like to write my own setup.rb. This is my final objective.

This is the first time that I try to write an installer and I don't know how to start. I carried out some research on Google but I can't find what I'm really looking for.

Can anyone suggest me any books or manual where I can learn to put the files on the right place (or whatever the installers do on Linux OS)? To put it better I would like to learn the basics of "how to install source code" in Linux systems and then apply the theory to try to install my ruby scripts.

Any suggestion is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a gem for it ? This is the best packaging system we know for ruby and you can just distribute a .gem file that can be installed with a simple gem command.

Check http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem